# Trying to boot with windows 7 CD, but keyboard is disabled

Tags: windows-7, boot

I can't boot my computer into the windows 7 CD to re-install by OS from scratch b/c when it says 'press any key to read from cd' (or whatever that message is) my keyboard doesn't seem to respond.

My keyboard also doesn't work when it says that my computer crashed and when it gives the option to boot up in safe mode, my keywboard doesnt' respond and it just loads in normal mode.

My keyboard DOES work as I am able to boot into the bios etc.

Is there a way to get around this somehow?  Could this be a virus?

The reason I am doing this is I already reloaded my o/s but I after about 10 minutes of computer usage the computer goes blank and gives the message that it can't read from a device, which is the same message I was getting before reloading windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

There was a bios setting that let me 'enable legacy USB keyboard' setting.  No idea why it is called legacy!

Comment: Maybe they stopped support for the device, so the drivers are from a prior generation.